Stringified JSON data won't INSERT into mySQL(verified json format)
I'm not able to insert a JSON string into a mySQL table.
CREATE TABLE registered (
    id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name nvarchar(128) NOT NULL,
    panels JSON NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

app.post("/registered", (req, res) => {
  let data = req.body;
  let sqlPost = `INSERT INTO registered (name, panels) VALUES ("${data.name}", "${data.panels}")`;
  db.query(sqlPost, (error, result) => {
    if (error) return res.json(error);
    res.send({
      message: "Registered.",
    });
  });
});

${data.panels} looks like {"panels":["uti","wound"]}. I verified the JSON format.
The error I'm getting is the following.
code: "ER_PARSE_ERROR"
errno: 1064
sql: "INSERT INTO registered \n (name, panels) \n VALUES (\"safas\", \"{\"panels\":[\"uti\",\"wound\"]}\")"
sqlMessage: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'panels\":[\"uti\",\"wound\"]}\",' at line 3"
sqlState: "42000"

I've been messing around with this too long. What the hell is wrong here?
I tried getting rid of the double quotes around the ${data.panels}. I verified the json.

In the mysql client. INSERT INTO t1 VALUES ("test", '{ "panels": ["one", "two"] }' ); works, where the second field is of type JSON.

You can also use this syntax: INSERT INTO t1 VALUES ("test2", JSON_OBJECT("panels", JSON_ARRAY("one", "two") ) ); with the same result.

Thanks for the suggestions, but I was trying to do it with a variable.

I didn't really look into the docs for this one, but I found a similar question on stackoverflow that might solve your problem. My guess is that you need single quotation marks around the JSON values while inserting them.

Shut the front door. It worked! Sometimes you just stare at things for way too long. Much appreciated.
